# Cannot import module when using memory_profiler

Tags: python, profiling, argparse, python-import

I'm trying to use [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler), but I run into a problem that is isolated in example.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python 
import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Dummy description')
    parser.add_argument('--option',  action='store_true')
    return parser.parse_args() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_args()
```

So basically only using argparse. Standalone this runs fine (I have Python3.3). However, when I issue

```
$ python -m memory_profiler example.py
```

I get a the error:

```
NameError: global name 'argparse' is not defined
```

Furthermore if I put the line

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Dummy description')
```

Underneath

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
```

And I comment out the function call to parse_args(), then I don't get the error.

Anyone an idea what goes wrong here?

Comment: Could you show the output of a simple `python --version`? I suspect that you are using a different interpreter version to launch your script than to run under memory profiling, because `argparse` should be standard in 3.x.

Comment: For me it works fine under 2.7 and only gives the error for python 2.6

Comment: It should be fixed within the current version of memory_profiler (0.27)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the memory-profiler does not use the current directory in its `PYTHONPATH` so my fix has been to use the following command:

`PYTHONPATH=./<CORRECT_PATH> python -m memory_profiler example.py`